# Disable a button where the Id that starts with

Tags: javascript

My buttons (it's inside a for loop) get a name from the database using `.getName()`

I'm trying to disable a button in javascript based on that name. But I can't seem to find the right way. Any help please?

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm startDocker" id="start-<%=environment.getName()%>" name="<%=environment.getName()%>">Start</button>
```

**This code is wrong**.Now I wanted to disable the button with a the `container.containerName`

```
 $('start-' + container.containerName).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: forgot the #....